# Mesmo código resultado diferente (Visual Studio 2012 X dotnetfiddle.net)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Segue imagem com os resultado nas duas plataformas, tem alguma explicação ou é um bug no compilador online?

Os dois são *console application*, a única diferença é que no *VS* está sendo compilado com dotNet4 enquanto o [dotnetfiddle.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsohB.png) dotnet4.5

```
    var textBoxValor = "10.8";
    decimal variavel = Decimal.Parse(textBoxValor.Replace(".", ","));

    textBoxValor = "10.8";
    var variavel2 = Decimal.Parse(textBoxValor);
```

Como a imagem não está boa, segue o resultado obtito respectivamente no VS e no site *dotnetfiddle.net*

> **VS:** variável:  10.8 variável2: 108
>
> **dotnetfiddle.net:** variável:  108 variável2: 10.8

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diferença existe por conta da cultura no qual o programa está rodando.

O teu programa no VS está com cultura `pt-BR`, que tem como separador de decimal a virgula (','), enquanto que no dotnetfiddle a cultura está *provavelmente* em `en-US`, que por sua vez conta com o ponto '.' como o separador de decimal.

Para receber sempre o mesmo resultado, você precisa usar a sobrecarga do método `Decimal.Parse` que recebe um `IFormatProvider` como um parâmetro. Se for usado o `Decimal.Parse` sem essa sobrecarga é utilizada a cultura na qual o programa esta rodando. Por isso que quando tu converte o valor 10,8 no dotnetfiddle ele se transforma em 108, pois o "," não é o separador de decimal da `Culture` em que o programa está rodando lá.

Exemplos de utilização do `Decimal.Parse` com a especificação da cultura a ser utilizada:

```
Decimal.Parse(textBoxValor, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

ou

```
Decimal.Parse(textBoxValor, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"));
Decimal.Parse(textBoxValor, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

etc...

Comment: Desconfiava disso, tem como postar um código de como resolver para ter os dois resultados iguais? Daí marco como conluído. @marciano-andrade

Comment: @HStackOverflow Editei a resposta, da uma olhada.

Comment: Obrigado @marciano-andrade.